# How to use AppleScript check if a menu item checked

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-big-sur

[see my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdJTV.png)

I want to get the value of the menu item "Set as system proxy" (whether if it has been checked).

The problem is if I want to get that value I have to click that menu first and find the menu item. But I want it to be done in the background since I want it to be executed every 5 seconds.

My code goes like this

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "ClashX"
        click (menu bar itm 1 of menu bar 2)
        get value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu item "Set as system proxy" of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end tell
```

(^^^^ This opens that menu over and over again)
and when I delete the line "click (menu bar itm 1 of menu bar 2)", which is

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "ClashX"
        get value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of menu item "Set as system proxy" of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end tell
```

the script cannot be done, error "System Events got an error: Can’t get menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of process "ClashX". Invalid index." number -1719 from menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of process "ClashX"

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do anything like that in the background, since the UI needs to be active in order to script it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know whether or not the **Set as system proxy** *menu item* is checked for **ClashX**, you can check the *value* of the **proxyPortAutoSet** *key* in its *preferences plist file*, e.g.:

In **Terminal**:

```bash
defaults read com.west2online.ClashX 'proxyPortAutoSet'
```

Returns `1` when checked, and `0` when **not** checked.

If you want to use it in **AppleScript**, use a `do shell script` *command*, e.g.:

```applescript
set menuItemIsChecked to ¬
    (do shell script ¬
        "defaults read com.west2online.CrashX 'proxyPortAutoSet'") ¬
        as boolean

if menuItemIsChecked then
    
    # Your code goes here.
    
    
end if
```

Comment: Thank you so much! and is there any way I can "click" this using command line?

Comment: @Samuel032xx, You can use the `osascript` _command_ to run **AppleScript** _code_ from the _command line_, or in a _shell script_. Have a look at the _manual page_ for `osascript`. You can read the _manual page_ for _`command`_ in **Terminal** by typing _`command`_ and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

Comment: I mean if I use script then it operate like real "click" right (open the menu-focus-click), but since we can check its check-status via command line, can we somehow change its status (turn on/off) via command line too?

Comment: @Samuel032xx, Yes, you can change the _value_ of the `proxyPortAutoSet ` _key_ using the `defaults` _command_, e.g. `defaults write com.west2online.ClashX 'proxyPortAutoSet' -bool true` will check the target _menu item_, and setting it to `false` will uncheck the target _menu item_.